# Firebase Multi Level database handeling in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i know how to insert single level data into firebase database. But i want to insert the values and get the values from firebase database with multilevel structure.

I am having dictionary in the structure of `[String: [String: [String]]]` , i want to insert this value into the table `my-test-table` with my own key as `my-sample-key`. then i want to fetch the data using `my-sample-key` with the same dictionay format.

Is it possible in firebase database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: It works

```
//Save Data
    let myDictionary = [String: [String: [String]]]()

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("allOfMyDictionarys").child("my-sample-key")
    ref.setValue(myDictionary)

    // Recive data
    ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if let data = snap.value as? [String: [String: [String]]]{
            //Do something here
        }
    }
```

Because Firebase works with JSON like Data structure you dont have things like Tables any more. So you don't need your 'my-test-table' because there is just one file. In order to struct the data I added the 'allOfMyDictionarys' child. Another advantage of the JSON format is you can just save dictionaries of Array without any problems.